# Jenkins Groovy Pipeline org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am retrieving an XML file from a remote host and parsing it using `XmlParser`. The content of the file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Metrics> <Safety> <score>81.00</score> <Percentrules>98.00</Percentrules> </Safety> </Metrics>
```

I am able to retrieve the score value in the following way when I execute the script outside the Groovy sandbox.

```
         def report = readFile(file: 'Qualitycheck.xml')
         def metrics = new XmlParser().parseText(report)
         println metrics
         double score = Double.parseDouble(metrics.Safety.score[0].value()[0])
```

However, when I execute the script using SCM I get the following:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node
```

The issue persist even though I have installed the `Permissive-Script-Security-Plugin` and enabled the plugin using the `-Dpermissive-script-security.enabled=no_security`JVM option. Is there something different about this method? No other method is causing issues. Why?

**Edit**

I decided to use `XmlSlurper()`, and retrieved the value `81.00`. However the result was type `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren`

```
         def metrics2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(report)
         def score = metrics2.Safety.score
         print score
         print score.getClass()
         => 81.0098.00
         => groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren
```

How do I use `XmlSlurper` to extract the value `81.00` and cast it as `double`? Will that be a good alternative?

Comment: Still struggling with this. Why is the `sandbox.RejectedAccessException` is being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some issues with the script sandbox with Node and NodeList field access. You can work around this like the following, its not nice but works at least.

```js
node() {
    def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/Qualitycheck.xml"
    def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
    print Double.parseDouble(rootNode.value()[0].value()[0].value()[0])
    // Next line if position isnt fixed, can return an array
    // if theres more than 1 with structure "Safety.score", [0] at the end takes the first.
    print Double.parseDouble(rootNode.find{it.name() == "Safety"}.value().find{it.name() == "score"}.value()[0])
}
```

You also need to approve following signatures in the In-process Script Approval section in Manage Jenkins menu.

```
method groovy.util.Node name
method groovy.util.Node value
method groovy.util.XmlParser parseText java.lang.String
new groovy.util.XmlParser
staticMethod java.lang.Double parseDouble java.lang.String
staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods find java.lang.Object groovy.lang.Closure
```

Comment: Great, thanks. yes there seem to have been something wrong with the node object. I am not sure what it might have been. it worked.